# from dataGridView1.Rows.Clear() until end to my code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Please Let me explain of there is something weird going on to my codes with my visual studio pro. There are no error messages of disconnected loops. It seems like I give up to check something wrong all files of my point of sales project. So until code below works fine.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into salesproducts(saleid,productname,qty,grosstotal)values(@saleid,@productname,@qty,@grosstotal)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saleid", lbinvoice.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);


                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd1.Connection = con;
                    cmd1.CommandText = "insert into salesmain(id,date,time,cashername,qty,grosstotal)values(@id,@date,@time,@cashername,@qty,@grosstotal)";
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lbinvoice.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", lbldate.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", lbltime.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cashername", label6.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", lbitems.Text);

                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", lbtotal.Text);

                    con.Open();
                   int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   int y = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Record added ..........");


                    updatedb();


                   }

               }

           catch (Exception ex)
          {
              //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

       finally
      {
          con.Close();
      }
    }


// everything worked fine of project till now......
```

but after add these codes from
like this now then nothing worked.

```
                    updatedb();

        //Nothing worked from here...

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                    lbtotal.Text = "0";
                    lbitems.Text = "0";
                    txtno.Focus();
                    totalPrice = 0;

                con.Close();
                invoice();
     }
           }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
       }
```

Sorry, I couldn't display the picture wholly screenshot or there is no permission here whatever. Please click down the below links.

[Please watch the sales window here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcWs7.png)

[then please watch this one to know whats not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JN5D.png)

I hope to find a solution without adding extra codes of files. Thanks

Comment: Put either break point at catch or remove the try catch to see if any exceptions!

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue in my test, but everything works fine. All the controls can be reset. I noticed that you called method `updatedb()` and `invoice()`. Could you provide the specified code of these methods? It's better if you can provide a simple demo that can reproduce the problem you encountered.

Comment: I've added additional infos please check it below.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not completely given codes to clarify the updateb() and invoice(). So for that reason, it's better off up like all codes in my specific file. So up like this.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace superpos3
{
    public partial class salesn : Form
    {
        public salesn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       public static int totalPrice = 0;
        public static int payment = 0;
        public static int balance = 0;

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server= localhost; database =superpos;  username= root; password=; ");


        public void invoice()
        {

            con.Open();
            string query = "select max(id) from salesmain ";
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            MySqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                string val = dr[0].ToString();
                if (val == "")
                {
                    lbinvoice.Text = "1";

                }
                else
                {
                    int a;

                    a = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                    a = a + 1;
                    lbinvoice.Text = a.ToString();



                }
                con.Close();
            }

        }





        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtno_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                txtqty.Enabled = true;
                txtqty.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void txtqty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {

                try
                {

                    string txt = "select * from products where id='" + txtno.Text + "'";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(txt, con);
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        int price = int.Parse(txtqty.Text.ToString()) * int.Parse(r[4].ToString());
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + price;
                        //discount
                        // totalPrice = totalPrice - totalPrice* Payment.discount/100;

                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.RowCount, r[0], r[1], txtqty.Text.Trim(), r[4], price);

                    }
                    lbitems.Text = " " + (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) + "";
                    lbtotal.Text = " " + totalPrice + " ";

                    con.Close();

                }






                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ee.Message, "Error From Database");
                }

                txtno.Focus();
                txtno.Clear();

                txtqty.Enabled = false;
                txtqty.Clear();

            }

        }


        private void txtqty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private string name;

        public string Staffname
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }

        }



      public void updatedb()
        {

            for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
            {


                string itmno = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                string itmqty = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                string t = "select * from products where id= '"+ itmno + "'";

                string oldqty = "", newqty = "";


                Connnew.DbSearch(t);


                while (Connnew.dr.Read())
                {

                    oldqty = Connnew.dr[5].ToString();
                    newqty = (int.Parse(oldqty) - int.Parse(itmqty)).ToString();
                }

                string t2 = "update products SET qty = '" + newqty + "' WHERE id = '" + itmno + "'";
                //t2 = t2.Replace("{0}", itmno);
                //t2 = t2.Replace("{2}", newqty);
                Connnew.DbUpdate(t2);
            }


        }


        private void salesn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label6.Text = Staffname;
            lbldate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            lbltime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

            invoice();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into salesproducts(saleid,productname,qty,grosstotal)values(@saleid,@productname,@qty,@grosstotal)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saleid", lbinvoice.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);


                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd1.Connection = con;
                    cmd1.CommandText = "insert into salesmain(id,date,time,cashername,qty,grosstotal)values(@id,@date,@time,@cashername,@qty,@grosstotal)";
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lbinvoice.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", lbldate.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", lbltime.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cashername", label6.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", lbitems.Text);

                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", lbtotal.Text);

                    con.Open();
                   int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   int y = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Record added ..........");
                    updatedb();
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                    lbtotal.Text = "0";
                    lbitems.Text = "0";
                    txtno.Focus();
                    totalPrice = 0;

                    con.Close();
                    invoice();

                }
               }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
           }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pay p = new pay();
            p.Show();
        }

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }   
}
```

And I'm seeing everything is fine and still not find the issue of those.

And the connected with above related to Connnew.DbSearch(t) that "Connnew" is like:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace superpos3
{
    class Connnew
    {

        public static MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server= localhost; database =superpos; username= root; password=; ");
        public static MySqlCommand poscmd = new MySqlCommand();
        public static MySqlDataReader dr;

        public static void DbSearch(string txt)
        {

            con.Close();
            poscmd.Connection = con;
            poscmd.CommandText = txt;
            con.Open();
            dr = poscmd.ExecuteReader();
        }

        public static void DbUpdate(string txt)
        {
            con.Close();
            poscmd.Connection = con;
            poscmd.CommandText = txt;
            con.Open();
            poscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what is here the issue of the structure of codes or what is really going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I did not find the reason why `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` not work. But if you want to insert multiple data into database, you need to move `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` outside the `for statement`.

Comment: could you see my answer there some errors happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've just deleted catch block and seen this error on the line below.

```
// the error was pops to -->`string itmno = `dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();`
```

the error is:

```
System.NullReferenceException
      HResult=0x80004003
      Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
      Source=superpos3
      StackTrace:
       at superpos3.salesn.updatedb() in D:\superpos3\superpos3\superpos3\salesn.cs:line 174
       at superpos3.salesn.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\superpos3\superpos3\superpos3\salesn.cs:line 258
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at superpos3.Program.Main() in D:\superpos3\superpos3\superpos3\Program.cs:line 19
```

Comment: It seems that `dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1]` is null. Maybe you can add an `if statement` to check it, or use [Null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

Comment: You should not put `updatedb` in the `for statement`. Because after the first loop executed, the content in datagridview has been cleared.

Comment: I've barely understood in the end. So could you please tell me how it possible executed the updatetb clearly and then move up to the next  dataGridView1.Rows.Clear() until the invoice() loop.

Comment: As I mentioned before, you need to call the code that "reset controls" outside `for statement`. Besides, if you call `updatetb` in the for loop, there is no need to use another for loop in method `updatetb`.

Comment: could you please write up as a little example of code?