# My code is not working after dataGridView1.Rows.Clear() until end

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My code is not working as I expected and I give the question to last days but I only checked after 2 days and I suppose my chance is gone to being answered. If that's wrong I'm asked second time excuse me well.

I have this weird going on to my codes with my visual studio pro. There are no error messages of disconnected loops. It seems like I give up to check something wrong all files of my point of sales project.

And I've given to updateb() and invoice(). So it's better off up like all codes in my specific file. So up like this.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace superpos3
{
    public partial class salesn : Form
    {
        public salesn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       public static int totalPrice = 0;
        public static int payment = 0;
        public static int balance = 0;

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server= localhost; database =superpos;  username= root; password=; ");


        public void invoice()
        {

            con.Open();
            string query = "select max(id) from salesmain ";
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            MySqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                string val = dr[0].ToString();
                if (val == "")
                {
                    lbinvoice.Text = "1";

                }
                else
                {
                    int a;

                    a = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                    a = a + 1;
                    lbinvoice.Text = a.ToString();



                }
                con.Close();
            }

        }





        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtno_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                txtqty.Enabled = true;
                txtqty.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void txtqty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {

                try
                {

                    string txt = "select * from products where id='" + txtno.Text + "'";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(txt, con);
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        int price = int.Parse(txtqty.Text.ToString()) * int.Parse(r[4].ToString());
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + price;
                        //discount
                        // totalPrice = totalPrice - totalPrice* Payment.discount/100;

                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.RowCount, r[0], r[1], txtqty.Text.Trim(), r[4], price);

                    }
                    lbitems.Text = " " + (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) + "";
                    lbtotal.Text = " " + totalPrice + " ";

                    con.Close();

                }






                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ee.Message, "Error From Database");
                }

                txtno.Focus();
                txtno.Clear();

                txtqty.Enabled = false;
                txtqty.Clear();

            }

        }


        private void txtqty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private string name;

        public string Staffname
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }

        }



      public void updatedb()
        {

            for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
            {


                string itmno = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                string itmqty = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                string t = "select * from products where id= '"+ itmno + "'";

                string oldqty = "", newqty = "";


                Connnew.DbSearch(t);


                while (Connnew.dr.Read())
                {

                    oldqty = Connnew.dr[5].ToString();
                    newqty = (int.Parse(oldqty) - int.Parse(itmqty)).ToString();
                }

                string t2 = "update products SET qty = '" + newqty + "' WHERE id = '" + itmno + "'";
                //t2 = t2.Replace("{0}", itmno);
                //t2 = t2.Replace("{2}", newqty);
                Connnew.DbUpdate(t2);
            }


        }


        private void salesn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label6.Text = Staffname;
            lbldate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            lbltime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

            invoice();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into salesproducts(saleid,productname,qty,grosstotal)values(@saleid,@productname,@qty,@grosstotal)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saleid", lbinvoice.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);


                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd1.Connection = con;
                    cmd1.CommandText = "insert into salesmain(id,date,time,cashername,qty,grosstotal)values(@id,@date,@time,@cashername,@qty,@grosstotal)";
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lbinvoice.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", lbldate.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", lbltime.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cashername", label6.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", lbitems.Text);

                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", lbtotal.Text);

                    con.Open();
                   int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   int y = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Record added ..........");
                    updatedb();

             //until here everything worked fine but if additionally given below codes not wroking 
               even the updatedb().

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                    lbtotal.Text = "0";
                    lbitems.Text = "0";
                    txtno.Focus();
                    totalPrice = 0;

                    con.Close();
                    invoice();

                }
               }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
           }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pay p = new pay();
            p.Show();
        }

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }   
}
```

And I'm seeing everything is fine and still not find the issue of those.

And the connected with above related to Connnew.DbSearch(t) that "Connnew" is like:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace superpos3
{
    class Connnew
    {

        public static MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server= localhost; database =superpos; username= root; password=; ");
        public static MySqlCommand poscmd = new MySqlCommand();
        public static MySqlDataReader dr;

        public static void DbSearch(string txt)
        {

            con.Close();
            poscmd.Connection = con;
            poscmd.CommandText = txt;
            con.Open();
            dr = poscmd.ExecuteReader();
        }

        public static void DbUpdate(string txt)
        {
            con.Close();
            poscmd.Connection = con;
            poscmd.CommandText = txt;
            con.Open();
            poscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't display the picture wholly screenshot or there is no permission here whatever. Please click down the below links.

[please watch the sales window here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEnTy.png)

[then please watch this one to know whats not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktWeK.png)

Please let me know what is here the issue of the structure of codes or what is really going wrong...............(this question is ended and updated my question below)

I checked all but except the form1.cs file are irrelevant of the problem here. So additionally for here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace superpos3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 1;
            if (progressBar1.Value >= 100)
            {
                Login In = new Login();
                this.Hide();
                In.Show();

                timer1.Enabled = true;
                progressBar1.Visible = false;
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define *"not working"*. There is a bunch of code there and no questions

Comment: If the question is in the header so add the xml code too

Comment: Your catch block is doing nothing. Remove it or place a break point to see if you are getting any exceptions!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62117741/from-datagridview1-rows-clear-until-end-to-my-code please do not open same question multiple times, it will be probably closed as it is against the rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates instead try to update/enhance your original question

Comment: Okay, I knew it. I was thinking no one sees my post because I passed days no answered. Well understood! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've just deleted catch block and seen this error on the line below.

```
`string itmno = `dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();` 

The error is:System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=superpos3
  StackTrace:
   at superpos3.salesn.updatedb() in D:\superpos3\superpos3\superpos3\salesn.cs:line 174
   at superpos3.salesn.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\superpos3\superpos3\superpos3\salesn.cs:line 258
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at superpos3.Program.Main() in D:\superpos3\superpos3\superpos3\Program.cs:line 19
```

sorry I've missed the info here:
[Please watch the sales window here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttX5p.png)

[then please watch this one to know whats not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycf4a.png)

Comment: Is this your answer? If this is an update to your question then update the question! https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: Thanks the link! And sorry, I wanted to let you know what you said as to remove the catch block. So then I add another question to add another answer! So I don't know it is a question or answer. Please let me know what is the way better solution to this only.

Comment: Based on my test, I suggest that you place the    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); out side of the for loop. Because it will clear all the datagridview, it may cause variable itmno to be null. Besides, If you want to solve your problem better, it is best for you to upload your project here.

Comment: I've updated the question. So I've seen there is no variable inside of the loop. But could you revise any answer, please? And I've checked all my files and only find a useful connection towards the project was only the form1.cs file there that error message was in line 19 of (form mainForm).

Comment: @BilguunEnkhee, I suggest that you remove the for sentence in the updatedb method, because updatedb method already in the for sentence.

Comment: If  remove the all sentence the updatedb method will not work. I'm looking for get to work to updatedb method. If updatedb();  get Inside the loop error is on the line of string itmno = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); like above.

Answer (score 0):

General recommendation. Please consider changing the code in many places. And don't wrap the MySqlConnection into object because it is already object oriented.
You should not add parameters and open connection at each iteration like this:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into salesproducts(saleid,productname,qty,grosstotal)values(@saleid,@productname,@qty,@grosstotal)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saleid", lbinvoice.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);


                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd1.Connection = con;
                    cmd1.CommandText = "insert into salesmain(id,date,time,cashername,qty,grosstotal)values(@id,@date,@time,@cashername,@qty,@grosstotal)";
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lbinvoice.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", lbldate.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", lbltime.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cashername", label6.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", lbitems.Text);

                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", lbtotal.Text);

                    con.Open();
```

Instead if should be done like this:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();

                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into salesproducts(saleid,productname,qty,grosstotal)values(@saleid,@productname,@qty,@grosstotal)";
                MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd1.Connection = con;
                cmd1.CommandText = "insert into salesmain(id,date,time,cashername,qty,grosstotal)values(@id,@date,@time,@cashername,@qty,@grosstotal)";

                cmd.Parameters.Add ("@saleid", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters.Add ("@productname", SqlDbType.String);
                cmd.Parameters.Add ("@qty", ...);
                cmd.Parameters.Add ("@grosstotal", ...);


                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", ...);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@date", ...);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@time", ...);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@cashername", ...);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@qty", ...);



                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    cmd.Parameters["@saleid"] = lbinvoice.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters["@productname"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@qty"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
                ....
                }
                con.Close();
```

Also consider opening the connection only once at the beginning of the program and close it only once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

[exception unhandled error message --> please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxyh6.png)

WHen the inside of for loop in updateb() method the window shows like above picture. 
I'm looking for how to get work the updateb() method inside the or outside of button1_Click void. So please provide me the best possible answer with example of codes. Or if asking some codes or not clear information so let me know.